# Trying to edit information in my list of names using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, logic

I'm trying to figure out a good way to edit information I have in my current phonebook list made with angular..

I want to know any good ways of editing inline data or non-inline way. I was going towards using binding, because the information below is binded to each entry. Some ideas and methods is all I'm looking for.

I have an input box for the name , phone and address that appends below for each table row goes into the table data

Currently the headers are displayed as below:

Name:John    Phone:555-555-5555    Address: 123 park place

Comment: Angular core provides you with tools for 2 way binding so what is the specific problem?

Comment: I know angular core has 2 way binding. I'm interesting in finding another way.

Comment: Another way to do what specifically? Can copy an object and edit that or edit live version using 2 way binding.  There really is no different way than using `ng-model`